# RecyclerView, with DiffUtil and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days and could really use some help and understanding on how to setup RecylerView(RV) with DiffUtil, seems whatever I try I can't get the RV to update. I'll run through what I have and hopefully, someone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

App start

- Create ViewModel,

  - The LiveDataList is then populated in the ViewModel.
- The RV is instantiated

  - The LayoutManager and the ListAdapter are applied to the RV.
- ItemTouchHelper is attached to the RecyclerView allowing items to be deleted from the LiveDataList when swiped to the left.
- The LiveDataList is observed, My understanding is when a change happens to the list, the observer will submit the List to the AdapterList to compare it with the old list if there is a difference between the original submitted listed and the modified list the AdapterList will update the RecyclerView.

Why is the observer not being called to update when an item is added or removed from the list LiveDataList.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var myAdapter = RVAdapter()
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(savedInstanceState: Bundle? ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Initialize the ViewModel, that stores the userList. 
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        // Creates list of users
        addUser()

        // Link an RV object to view
        val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        // apply RV Settings. 
        rv.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter= myAdapter
        }

        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
             override fun onMove(...) {
                 // move items isn't used. 
             }

             override fun onSwipe(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                 // When I swipe a second item, the app crashes.
                 val editList: MutableList<User>? = viewModel.usersList?.value as MutableList<User>?
                 editList?.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                 viewModel.usersList?.postValue(userList)
             }
        }).attachtoRecyclerView(rv)
     
        // The observer will run after swiping an item but the UI doesn't update. 
        viewModel.usersList?observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {
                // Should update list but it doesn't
                myAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
    }

    private fun addUser() {
        // Shouldn't there be away to add Items directly to list in ViewModel.
        val newList: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()
        newList.add(User("Shawn", 1)
        newList.add(User("Shannon", 2)
        newList.add(User("Don", 3)

        viewModel.userList?.postValue(newList)
}
```

Data class: This is pretty basic and not much happening here.

```
data class User(val name: String, val accountNumber: Int) {
}
```

ViewModel: MyViewModel only stores the MutableLiveDat

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val usersList: MutableLiveData<List<User>>? = MutableLiveData() 
}
```

RecycleView Adapter

```
class RVAdapter : ListAdapter<User, RVAdapter.ViewHolder>(MyDiffCallback() {
    
    // This DiffUtil class never gets called not even on startup.
    class MyDiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {
            return oldItem.name == newItem.name
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    ... Rest of RV is working fine but can be included if it's helpful.  
}
```

What can be done so when an item is deleted or added from the LiveData List that the observer will pass the modified list to the ListAdapter?

StackTrace included
Index outbounds.

```
2020-10-05 20:14:16.538 19042-19042/com.example.practicerecyclerview2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.practicerecyclerview2, PID: 19042
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.example.practicerecyclerview2.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onSwiped(MainActivity.kt:100)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper$4.run(ItemTouchHelper.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: what is viewModel.users?.postValue(userList) ?  you dont have a userList reference.. is it editList? you dont have a usersList in your viewModel, do you?!

Comment: Good Catch @HenriqueVasconcellos, that was a type-o in the question users in ViewModel should have been usersList.

Comment: `// When I swipe a second item, the app crashes.` . Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @theapache64 Stack Track is included, It appears to be an index outbounds problem.

Comment: Yes. You're trying to remove an item that doesn't exist in the index. What is `viewHolder.adapterPosition` ?

Comment: add `submitList` code

Comment: @Autocrab submit is used in the userList Observer, is there another place you would recommend using it.

Comment: I just want to see what does this method, can you post method code?))

Comment: @Autocrab I'm not sure what method you are referring to, The only thing I haven't haven't posted from the main activity is an onClick fun that tells the size of the list and some Log tags.

Comment: `myAdapter.submitList(it)` - can you post code of this method?

Comment: @Autocrab That's an auto-generated method in the list adapter. There's not a lot in there do you still want to see it?

Comment: I cant finde where you set the adapter to the recucycler, do you `rv.adapter = myAdapter`?

Comment: I think you should add adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.adapterPosition) after calling removeAt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `ListAdapter` is not updating is that it cannot find a difference in the list you submit, because you already modified it. This way the `notifyDataChanged()` methods are not called and you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on a second swipe, because that item does not exist anymore.

The way to solve it is to modify and submit a *copy* of the list:

```
override fun onSwipe(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    val editList: MutableList<User>? = viewModel.usersList?.value as MutableList<User>?
    val editListCopy = editList?.toMutableList()
    editListCopy?.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    viewModel.users?.postValue(editListCopy)
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around why the ListAdapter doesn't find a difference in the list if you add or remove an item from the list. Are you saying the AdapterList doesn't check modifications to a List but needs a new list object?

Comment: Yes, it holds a reference to the same list you are modifying. Internally it does an equality check on the submitted list and its current list, but they are the same!

Comment: Also note that `ListAdapter` holds a reference to items in the list too. So if you modify an item it doesn't see a change, because we make a 'shallow copy' (new list, but the same items). To make `ListAdapter` see changes to items we have to make a 'deep copy' (new list and new items). The copy-function on data classes is shallow, so you have to do your own deep copy.

Comment: Thanks, @BramStoker this makes so much sense,

Comment: @Bram Stoker I have a similar use case.  Can you provide Java example of deep copy?